# AWS Lambda with VPC can't communicate with internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I'm create sample Lambda, create VPC using vpc-privatepublic.yaml (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html), connect Lambda to VPC then test internet access: inside Lambda network IP like 169.254.50.5 (not from VPC range), and Lambda app can't connect to internet

for test this i'm use simple python code:
   `try: socket.create_connection(("8.8.8.8", 53), timeout=1) return("Success!!!") except OSError: return("No internet")`

Answer (score 2):

When you deploy a Lambda function to a VPC, it does not get a public IP address. That means it can't communicate with anything outside of the VPC.

Here are your options for solving this issue:

1. If you switch your VPC to IPv6, your Lambda functions [will get a public IP](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/10/aws-lambda-ipv6-outbound-connections-vpc/) and have access to the Internet.
2. If you add a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html), and move the Lambda function to private VPC subnets that have a route to the NAT Gateway, then the functions will have access to the Internet.
3. If your Lambda function doesn't actually need to access anything inside the VPC, then by far the easiest way to solve your issue is just to remove the VPC configuration from the Lambda function, and it will then have access to the Internet.

Comment: I'm create 
Subnet: 
eu-west-1a
APP-subnet-public1-eu-west-1a
13.0.0.0/18

Then create Internet gateway, attach to this subnet and creato route 0.0.0.0/0 -> Internet router.
I understand that this should have been enough, but it’s not.

Comment: A resource in a VPC has to have a public IP in order to directly use the Internet Gateway. The Lambda function in the VPC doesn't have a public IP. So the Lambda function needs to be deployed in a subnet with a route to a NAT Gateway instead.